# Checking Member Variable of Enum Without Iterating

Tags: java, performance, enums

I have an enum like that:

```
public enum Lang {
    TR("tr"),
    EN("en"),
    SE("se");

 private String langName;

 private Lang(String langName) {
        this.langName = langName;
    }
}
```

at another class I want to check whether a langName exists or not. If I put a getter method I can iterate over langNames:

```
for (Lang langEnum : Lang.values()) {
        langEnum.getLangName();
}
```

However my enum may be too long and I don't want to iterate over an array. I want to use a Map or Set. On the other hand I don't want to another variable within my enum.

How can I check whether my enum has a langName or not?

Comment: If you want to use a `Map`, then make a `Map` a static variable in your enum and initialize it in a `static {...}` block.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I did it. However does it a good approach for a code design?

Comment: If you want to use a `Map` for performance, then...it's really your only option.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if every enum constant represents a language (as the code seems to suggest), then I would use an EnumSet.

```
Set<Lang> langs = EnumSet.allOf(Lang.class);
```

And then I can check if a language is already there. Like

```
if(langs.contains(Lang.EN) {
  //...
}
```

Not sure if this is the answer you were looking for. The contains method of EnumSet would not even iterate over the internal collection. The internal collection would be stored in an array and finding an element is calculated based on a hash. So, this in fact, should achieve what you requested in the question.

Comment: I want to pass "tr" and checker whether is there an Enum has a langName or not.

Comment: @kamaci Well, if "tr" should correspond to an enum named as `Lang.TR` then you can use [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18318794/697630) suggesting the use of `Lang.valueOf(langName.toUpperCase())`. And again, no need for iterations of any kind.

Comment: but It is not always true that uppercase of langName will be value of Lang everytime.

Comment: @kamaci You are out of luck, I guess you will need to populate a map as you create your enums as suggested in another comment.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `valueOf`?

```
Lang lang = null;

try {
  lang = Lang.valueOf(enumName);
  // enum exists
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
  // enum does not exist
}
```

Since your enum name is just the language name capitalized, you can just capitalize the language name and pass it into `valueOf`.